# Changing Packaging Name With Lib Folder Android/Maven

Tags: android, maven

I am working on the build process for my project. Essentially I want to build 2 apps from the same source. I am using different profiles to do this.

I have managed to configure maven change the name and urls within the app. I have a need to change the packaging as well so both apps can be on a device at the same time.

My project is set up with a parent POM and 2 child POMs

The first child POM is a library it is packaged as an APKlib. The packaing is com.companylib

The second child POM is the creates the actual APK and references the apklib. this is packaged as com.company.

At the moment I am changing the packaing in the manifest with this config.

```
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                   <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <inherited>true</inherited>
                   <configuration>
                       <renameManifestPackage>${manifest_pakage}</renameManifestPackage>
                       <sign>
                           <debug>false</debug>
                       </sign>
                       <zipalign>
                           <verbose>true</verbose>
                           <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</inputApk>
                           <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk
                           </outputApk>
                       </zipalign>
                       <manifest>
                           <debuggable>true</debuggable>
                           <versionCodeAutoIncrement>true</versionCodeAutoIncrement>
                       </manifest>
                       <proguard>
                           <skip>true</skip>
                       </proguard>

                   </configuration>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                           <phase>process-resources</phase>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                       <execution>
                           <id>alignApk</id>
                           <phase>package</phase>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>zipalign</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>
```

I define manifest_pakage in the different profiles I use. This is defined in the first child POM.

Both profiles build fine and I can install both on the same device. However I run into a problem on the staging app when roboguice tries to reference the APKLIB. I receive the following error...

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
 1) No implementation for com.companylib.ServerComms.Senders.StringSenderImp annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=json) was bound.
   while locating com.companylib.ServerComms.Senders.StringSenderImp annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=json)
```

So it seems the packaging on the apklib isn't changed. The strange thing is that I replace the packaging on production and it works ok (tho I replace it with the same packaging).

Should I expect the build to change the packaging of the lib when set up like this?

Is it ok if the lib has a different package name from the main app?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did it like this and got  it working. (I am using Eclipse IDE )

1. Select the project and do a `file search` for the old package name and replace with the new package name. ( This would replace all the old package names inside the files of the project)
2. Right click on the `package --> Refactor --> Rename` . Replace with the new package name. This would replace the package config.

   ( If you do this before the first step and if you are having
   `.YourActivity` instead of the whole package name
   (`com.project.package.name.YourActivity`) declared in your manifest,
   it may cause errors)
3. Again select the project and do file search. This time it will show the annotated files if you are using `AndroidAnnotations` and replacing here with the new package name would replace its imports.

**Note:** If you are using your own plugins or libraries with the old package name, you may have to make sure it is the same in child `pom.xml` as it will also be replaced.

Hope this helps..! :) Happy coding..!